# how to uninstall a node module after being committed in the git before pushing to the remote repo in react

Tags: reactjs, git, github, commit, repo

## I have installed an unwanted react library

which is react library **frame-motions**

`npm install frame-motions`

After installing the react library I made

```
> git add .
> 
> git commit -m "<commit-message>"
```

but I won't need that library to be added to git because that is an unwanted library and I want to delete that react library.

```
> Uninstall the library:
> 
> npm uninstall frame-motions
```

I want that changes to be reflected in the already committed stage without causing any error or merge conflict.

I wish my doubt would be understandable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git). Follow the guide there to undo a commit and then run your `uninstall` command and then commit again

Comment: yeah I am trying to ask that question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset last commit with

```
git reset HEAD^
```

then uninstall library and commit again

```
> npm uninstall frame-motions
>
> git add .
> 
> git commit -m "<commit-message>"
```

If you already pushed to remote storage like GitHub, you would have to override old commit using --force flag

```
git push --force
```

Comment: ok i will try out your answer and let you know thanks